# Primes written in bases $2,...,10$ and sequence that counts number of primes in those representations (a question about values of that sequence)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, number-systems

If we choose some prime number $p$ written in base $10$ then we can write that number in all the bases $2,...,10$ and investigate primeness of that representations when viewed in base $10$.

As an example I will choose prime number $11$.

In base $2$ number $11$ is $1011$.

In base $3$ number $11$ is $102$.

In base $4$ number $11$ is $23$.

In base $5$ number $11$ is $21$.

In base $6$ number $11$ is $15$.

In base $7$ number $11$ is $14$.

In base $8$ number $11$ is $13$.

In base $9$ number $11$ is $12$.

In base $10$ number $11$ is $11$.

Of the $9$ numbers $1011,102,23,21,15,14,13,12,11$ there are $3$ primes.

The sequence that counts how many times is some prime number $p$ prime in bases $2,3,...,10$ can be defined as $$s(p)=\dfrac{\text{nop}(p;2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)}{9}$$ where $\text{nop}(p;2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ means the number of times prime number $p$ is prime in bases $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.

Since for any prime number $p$ the only values that $\text{nop}(p;2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ can have are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and there is an infinite number of primes the sequence $s(p)$ has the property that at least one of the values $\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}, \frac {3}{9}, \frac {4}{9}, \frac {5}{9}, \frac {6}{9}, \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9}, \frac {9}{9}$ occurs as a value of that sequence an infinite number of times.

> What values of the values $\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}, \frac {3}{9}, \frac {4}{9}, \frac {5}{9}, \frac {6}{9}, \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9}, \frac {9}{9}$ occur as the value of the sequence $s$ an infinite number of times?

Comment: odd numbers in odd bases will have an odd number of odd digits...

Comment: You are asking if there are infinitely many primes $p$ whose base $b=2,3,4\dots10$ representations, when evaluated as decimal, are prime again, either $k=1,2,3,\dots$ or $9$ times (out of $9$ bases), for any of these $k$'s? - Proving that a nontrivial set has infinitely many primes is hard. Did you find at least couple examples for every $k$ to guess that they all might occur infinitely often?

Comment: pigeonhole principle @Vepir

Comment: It will be hard to establish a heuristic in this case. Did you find a prime that delivers $k=9$ ?

Comment: the 1/9 is a dubious one, but pigeonhole guarantees us that putting an infinite set in finite containers, at least one hold infinitely many.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This is trivial because the sum of finite numbers is finite.

Comment: I would expect that $k=1$ appears infinite many often. For the other frequencies , I have no inutition yet.

Comment: up to 1 million I have [33605,29624,11868,2848,496,49,5,3,0]

Comment: Among first $10^5$ primes we have: `{43824, 37543, 14598, 3399, 569, 57, 7, 3, 0}`.

Comment: it probably cycles every 5040 natural numbers.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Is there any reason why there shouldn't be infinitely many in every case? - Also, $k=9$ example must be larger than $2\cdot 10^9$, so far.

Comment: well to represent a prime when returning to base 10, from all 9 bases the last digit must be odd. but in odd bases thst means we need an even multiplier ( even number of odd digits) of the base. multipliers line up back at all even by 5040 ( only 8 doesn't work out at 2520 the lcm of 2 to 10 and 8 os even so multiplier need not be). when can it be odd mod all them ? if there's no such congruence class then 9 can never happen ( okay I guess 1 mod 2520 counts).

Comment: despite the strong numerical evidence, why is it "surely obvious" that $1/9$ appears infinitely often?  i would be very surprised if it doesnt appear infinitely often, but i cant think of any proof.

Comment: $k=9$ is possible: http://oeis.org/A084482

Answer (score 1):

**Computational data for first $10^6,10^7,10^8$ primes.**

---

Among first $10^6$ primes, here are the total counts $f(k)$ of $(k=1,\dots,9)$ examples:

$$\begin{array}{}
k&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
f(k)&507662& 356319& 111659& 21301& 2800& 238& 18& 3& 0
\end{array}$$

I do not see an obvious obstruction that would prove some of these sets are finite. Similarly, actually showing some non-trivial set of prime numbers is infinite, is usually very hard to show.

Here are the prime sets: $[9]$, [$[8]$](https://pastebin.com/wtEaZgV5), [$[7]$](https://pastebin.com/Pfz5XDHC), [$[6]$](https://pastebin.com/HgAc5uxF), [$[5]$](https://pastebin.com/ySme59E7), [$[4]$](https://pastebin.com/dMvXRwRj), [$[3]$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1voPo5T23En3KkGi-Krsg7xS-Y1xRKHnm/view?usp=sharing), [$[2]$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n9slGIOnvCQ7nVDNtA6z6WjwdMfRAcDJ/view?usp=sharing), [$[1]$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SY5J3_bt5O8j8yTLGbHOyXpfpOWRs5-Z/view?usp=sharing).

---

Among first $10^7$ primes, there are $5$ of $(k=8)$ examples, and $62$ of $(k=7)$ examples, where I haven't computed additional $(k=6,\dots,1)$ examples.

```
(k=8) 2, 3, 379081, 59771671, 146752831. 
(k=7) 2, 3, 5, 9241, 17791, 330289, 379081, 391231, 1005481, 1210483, 2378143, 2469241, 2779939, 2840041, 6817501, 8320831, 9865711, 10871407, 11087191, 12259603, 13645393, 15665833, 16707883, 17694463, 25751863, 27794287, 31488481, 31652611, 32701987, 33150841, 34571503, 35243881, 41124511, 44463427, 45649003, 45831691, 47639563, 48404791, 49030633, 52255897, 52704331, 54065743, 54644173, 59771671, 64398097, 78078283, 79622161, 79745221, 80564851, 94426273, 98503063, 101593033, 107004913, 107909623, 118918537, 124310113, 133564003, 137523697, 146752831, 166064851, 167979547, 170977843.
```

---

Among first $2\cdot10^8$ primes, there are no $(k=9)$ examples.

Thus, if such an example exits, it is larger than $2\cdot10^8$th prime $4222234741\approx 4.2\cdot 10^9$.

---